# Ion searchbar false event triggered on backspace key press in windows application

Tags: ionic3

When backspace key is pressed in search bar onInput() method is getting called before user stops clearing the text. What can be done to ignore this call and proceed with the action only when the user stops clearing text

```html
<ion-searchbar #mainSearchbar [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ionInput)="onInput($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue. instead of using ionInput I am listening to key up event.

```js
  handleSearchDown() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }

  handleSearchUp() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.getItems();
  }

  getItems() {
    var that = this;
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
    this.timeout = setTimeout(function () {
      that.searchList(that.searchText);
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  clearTimeout() {
    clearTimeout(this.timeout)
  }
```

```html
<ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchText" (keyup)="handleSearchUp()" (keydown)="handleSearchDown()" (ionClear)="clearTimeout()"></ion-searchbar>
```